# Get Bit 0 from Byte array

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have wrapped a C++ API in C#. This API fills the supplied memory location with a byte array that represents program settings. I need to get Bit 0 to determine its state. Here is the C++ API and  usage documentation:

```
DECL_FOOAPIDLL DWORD WINAPI FOO_GetVal(
VOID *Val,  //pointer to memory where the data will be stored by the function
DWORD Len,  //length of Val in bytes
DWORD Id    //identification number of the parameter
);
```

Here is my C# wrapper and call (what i assume to be correct):

```
        [DllImport(FOO_API, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static public extern uint FOO_GetVal(IntPtr val, uint len, uint id);


        IntPtr Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(5);
        uint hr = NativeWrapper.FOO_GetVal(Ptr, 5, 1181);

        var byteArray = new byte[5];
        Marshal.Copy(Ptr, byteArray, 0, 5);


        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Ptr);
```

How do i get bit 0?

I've tried (with no success):

```
bool b = GetBit(bytearray[0],0);

private bool GetBit(byte b, int bitnum)
{
    return (b & (1 << nitnum)) != 0;
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Getting the first byte and bit twiddling it should give you its state.

Comment: Please figure out what half of the code is not working and edit question accordingly: do you have problem with marshaling OR you have problem with getting a particular bit from give byte array?

Comment: exactly what my question states... i need bit 0 from bytearray[]... the marshalling works fine, i'm unsure how to get bit 0 from the byte array....

Comment: The API returns '0', which means it was happy from what the documentation states...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my code was correct... the API vendor supplied me with the incorrect ID parameter (the 3rd value)... I appreciate all the comments and my new understanding of least to most significant bit explained by Guvante.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the most significant bit or the least significant bit?

Usually first refers to the most significant bit within a Byte and you are getting the least significant bit.

Try `GetBit(bytearray[0],7)`

Comment: unfortunately im not getting the correct return from that code

Comment: +1 - good point about most/least significant bit. The same true for bytes in the sequence...

Comment: i'm waiting on a resp from the API developer regarding least/most

Comment: developer states least significant bit holds the value i want

Comment: @Don: Your code appears to be doing that correctly. Have you checked the rest of the data returned? Also is there a potential for a byte ordering issue (for instance the developer is storing a 16 bit number) Usually I find it helps to get a result and look at it in a debugger window to ensure it lines up with my expectations.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) structure to make your life easier. Create the BitArray from your byte and you can check the bits you need. Remember what Guvante pointed out though - the bits may be stored from least significant to most significant. Windows and most Linux distros are [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), so that's probably a safe bet to make for a .Net program.

Comment: i added an upvote, but i don't think it makes this easier (in my opinion)